# Power function with recursion - java

Tags: java, recursion

Here's the working recursive power function alternative to Math.Pow class:

```
public class Powers {
    public static long pow(long x, long p) {
        if (p == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (p % 2 == 0) {
            long a = pow(x, (p / 2));
            return a * a; //This line
        } else {
            long a = pow(x, ((p - 1) / 2));
            return x * a * a; //This line
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to be clever and use as much recursion as possible by changing the lines mentioned above to `return pow(a, 2)` and `return x * pow(a, 2)`, I get a stack overflow error. I get that it should cause considerably more calls to `pow`, but I don't think it should loop like it appears to. Can anyone explain me through this? Thanks

Comment: @mikeyaworski this way is absolutely incorrect, because the speed of calculation power in your way is O(n), while in the original solution it was O(log n).

Comment: @ginz it's not "incorrect". It's a slower way of doing a calculation, yes, but it's fine for smallish values. I guess it would still use more stacks? I'm not sure, but it's a little simpler.

Comment: @mikeyaworski in OP's solution there was some point in doing recursion (it makes more sense), in your's - it's not, because it's easier here to do it with just a loop.

Comment: @ginz I'm not very savvy with recursion, but I rarely (not never) see a point in recursion vs a loop. Unless the backstacks are important, I don't see why his solution couldn't also be modeled with a loop. My point is that he's trying to force unnecessary recursion in there. Instead of `return a * a;` he wants to do `return pow(a, 2);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this you will get the following sequence of calls:

```
pow(a, 2) -> pow(a, 1) -> pow(a, 0) -> pow(1, 2) -> pow(1, 1) -> pow(1, 0) -> pow(1, 2) -> ...
```

Comment: @DavidWallace The call to `pow(a, 0)` returns 1, but then the line `return x * pow(a, 2)` from a previous incarnation gets executed and a is 1 at this point.

Comment: Sorry, I take it back.  I didn't read the question carefully enough.  I thought OP was saying they had the error with the code they had actually posted, not the modification they described underneath it.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You should either debug this with some IDE, or simply add some expression in the beginning of the method:

```
public static long pow(long x, long p) {
    System.out.println ("x = " + x + ", p = " + p);
    ...
```

Then, read the output, it will contain the sequence of calls of `pow`